how to parse unary expressions using parser combinators?
I'm trying to parse expressions using my own handwritten parser combintor library in Haskell. already I can parse binary expressions with the code below, that I found in dhall project, but I do not understand it properly.
this is how I defined my expressions:
data Expression
  = BinaryOperation Expression Operator Expression
  | UnaryOperation Operator Expression
  deriving (Show, Eq)

and this is the function I took from dhall project. you can read more of the dhall code at here
makeOperator :: Parser Operator -> Parser Expression -> Parser Expression
makeOperator parseOperator parseValue = do
  l0 <- parseValue
  fs <- many do
    operator <- do
      _ <- wsP
      parseOperator
    _ <- wsP
    r <- parseValue
    pure $ \l -> BinaryOperation l operator r
  pure $ foldl (\l f -> f l) l0 fs

I tried replicating the dhall code, by writing the code below to parse unary expressions, but it seems this code consumes the input and doesn't let the parsers with lower precedence do their job. E.g. +2 + 2 will become +2 and + 2 will be just leftover string of the parser.
makeOperatorUnary :: Parser Operator -> Parser Expression -> Parser Expression
makeOperatorUnary parseOperator parseValue = do
  operator <- parseOperator
  value <- parseValue
  pure $ UnaryOperation operator value

I would be glad if someone did explain how the dhall code exactly worked and lead me into the right direction.
thank you

Can you include more information? E.g. links to where you found this dhall parser, an example input which gives wrong results, and the name of the libraries you are using (I assume megaparsec).

I'm also confused by your replication of the dhall parser. The code you wrote below just seems like a completely different function.

The way the makeOperator combinator works, you supply it with a parser parseOperator for the set of equal precedence, left associative binary operators you're interested in (e.g., + and - binary operators at the same precedence), as well as a parser parseValue for parsing expressions at a higher precedence level (e.g., multiplication and division), and it implements precedence by parsing each of the parseValue-precedence expressions as self-contained units that are joined by the parseOperator operators at the current precedence level.
So, to parse binary + and - expressions, you want to use something like:
parseAddSub :: Parser Expression
parseAddSub = makeOperator parseBinaryPlusOrMinusOperator parseMulDiv

where parseBinaryPlusOrMinusOperator takes care of parsing the + and - operators, and parseMulDiv is the next highest precedence expression parser that will ensure that, say, 1*2 and 3*4 are parsed as units, so when joined by + in the expression 1*2+3*4, the result will end up being equivalent to (1*2)+(3*4), correctly implementing the precedence.
Your makeOperatorUnary combinator is similar.  It takes a parser for the unary operator of interest, say -, and then it takes a parser for higher precedence expressions.  That means that if you write:
parseUnaryMinus = makeOperatorUnary parseUnaryMinusOperator parseAddSub

then you're going to have a problem.  If you're trying to parse -3+4, this version of parseUnaryMinus will parse the unary - operator and then parse the entire 3+4 expression as a higher precedence parseAddSub expression, which will give the equivalent of -(3+4), which is wrong precedence.
You probably want to sneak unary minus in between parseAddSub and parseMulDiv, like this:
parseAddSub = makeOperator parseBinaryPlusOrMinusOperator parseUnaryMinus

parseUnaryMinus = makeOperatorUnary parseUnaryMinusOperator parseMulDiv

parseMulDiv = ...

This will accept something like 1+-3*4 as equivalent to 1+(-(3*4)), which is probably what you want.
You also need makeOperatorUnary to optionally parse the operator, the same way parseAddSub checks for, but doesn't require, binary + and - operators.  So, instead of your definition above, try:
makeOperatorUnary parseOperator parseValue
  =   UnaryOperation <$> parseOperator <*> parseValue
  <|> parseValue

Here's a simplified example without whitespace handling to illustrate the design:
import Data.Void
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

type Parser = Parsec Void String

data UnaryOperator = UnaryMinus
  deriving (Show)

data Operator = Plus | Minus | Times | Divide
  deriving (Show)

data Expression
  = Literal Int
  | BinaryOperation Expression Operator Expression
  | UnaryOperation UnaryOperator Expression
  deriving (Show)

makeOperator :: Parser Operator -> Parser Expression -> Parser Expression
makeOperator parseOperator parseValue = do
  l0 <- parseValue
  fs <- many $ do
    operator <- do
      parseOperator
    r <- parseValue
    pure $ \l -> BinaryOperation l operator r
  pure $ foldl (\l f -> f l) l0 fs

makeUnaryOperator :: Parser UnaryOperator -> Parser Expression -> Parser Expression
makeUnaryOperator parseOperator parseValue
  =   UnaryOperation <$> parseOperator <*> parseValue
  <|> parseValue


parseAddSub, parseUnaryMinus, parseMulDiv, parseFactor :: Parser Expression

parseAddSub = makeOperator (Plus <$ char '+' <|> Minus <$ char '-') parseUnaryMinus

parseUnaryMinus = makeUnaryOperator (UnaryMinus <$ char '-') parseMulDiv

parseMulDiv = makeOperator (Times <$ char '*' <|> Divide <$ char '/') parseFactor

parseFactor = Literal . read <$> some digitChar
  <|> between (char '(') (char ')') parseAddSub

main = do
  parseTest parseAddSub "1+-2*3"

